# Do all Kafka broker IPs have to be specified when producing a message

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have 3 broker kafka cluster with 3 zookeeper.

My question is if we have to give only one IP address in producer-console.sh file like below

```
/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 192.168.7.110:9092 --topic test
```

or all the three ip addressess

```
./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 192.168.7.110:9092,192.168.5.110:9092,192.168.3.111:9092 --topic test
```

What will happen if I provide only one IP to produce messages and that IP is shutdown after sometime. Will I be able to produce messages through that IP or not or I have to give all the IP addresses?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please edit the question and provide a better formatting else it is so clumsy to read(Also please see for the English).

Comment: Please be respectful when talking with others on StackOverflow. Down voting is done when the question is poorly written, when someone doesn't provide enough information about the problem, etc. I have done it for the first reason, when you edit the question, it can be removed!

Comment: Sorry I could do that but my previous edits aren't approved and are in pending approval. If they were approved I would have edited the question. But sorry for that.

Comment: OK I will see to it. I have edited the question. Once it gets approved, I will upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [Producer config](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs) docs, which describe the purpose of `bootstrap.servers` (`bootstrap-servers` / `broker-list` are synonyms):

> **A list of host/port pairs to use for establishing the initial connection to the Kafka cluster.**
>
> The client will make use of all servers irrespective of which servers are specified here for bootstrapping—this list only impacts the initial hosts used to discover the full set of servers. This list should be in the form host1:port1,host2:port2,....
>
> Since **these servers are just used for the initial connection to discover the full cluster membership** (which may change dynamically), **this list need not contain the full set of servers (you may want more than one, though, in case a server is down).**

So if you only provide one IP, and that IP is then shut down, your producer will subsequently fail when it tries to connect. But you could, for example, supply *two* IPs, so that if one fails the producer can still connect to a different one. But the broker to which the actual messages are sent is not impacted by this.

See [also this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53786980/clarification-on-the-broker-list-option-and-bootstrap-server-option-in-kafka).

Comment: means they are saying that if have cluster and i have to use all ip. This will help if any of the broker goes down

Comment: No need to provide all the ip. You may need to provide more than one ip just to make sure that when the producer connecting / starting to that broker IP is up. If all the listed broker ips are down, your new producer cannot connect to the cluster.

Comment: Thanks lot for your answer sir. I have tried with one ip and its workign fine but when that ip goes down from the cluster the producer not connecting to another leader ip automatically. In this time i have to pass that leader ip, so producer can send the data